# Why were the Avengers fighting each other?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In ***Captain America: Civil War*** you see that **Iron Man** has actually recruited some other avengers and then some way through the movie, you see  that the Avengers have teamed up 5 vs 5.

**Captain America** with **Ant man** and other Avengers and **Iron man**, **Vision**, **Spider-man**, **Black Panther** and Iron man's side kick on the other side.

**Why do they fight each other?**

**What is the point of this?**

Comment: the reason they are fighting is _the entire plot of the movie_....

Comment: This is probably the worst question I have asked at all.

Comment: Did you even bothered to watch movie before asking

Comment: @Panther By the way, yes I did watch the movie otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place.

Comment: Just below keywords... Share edit **delete**....... ????? ....... Profit!         ....seriously it will remove your negative points.

Comment: @Harper He can't delete the question because it has an upvoted answer (that of HorusKol). HorusKol would have to delete his answer first, or a moderator would have to delete the question for him.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The conflict in *Captain America: Civil War* is complicated, and the characters all have individual motivations - but the point of breaking the Avengers is the Sokovia Accords and the loyalty that Steve "Captain America" Rogers has towards his old friend Bucky (the Winter Soldier).

Rogers is distrustful of authority after the events of Winter Soldier - SHIELD had been almost completely infiltrated by Hydra, and had abused their uncountered power to eliminate any potential threat to Hydra as they were about to make grab for world domination. He sees the Sokovia Accords as another attempt for a shadowy group to control "enhanced" individuals such as himself and the other Avengers, and would prefer to follow his own moral compass. He's also out to protect his friend, Bucky Barnes.

Stark, on the other hand, is racked by guilt - we see that he didn't cope well after the attack on New York in the Avengers movie. He feels guilty for the events of Iron Man 3, and for Ultron and, ultimately, for what happened at Sokovia. He's seeking to make amends, and feels that his previous cavalier attitude is to blame for a lot of his earlier actions - he sees following the new rulebook as a way to assuage his guilt.

As for the others, I don't have a clear picture of the motivation of each character, but:

- Ant-Man: Ex-criminal, who is being mentored by Hank Pym, who distrusts Stark. Has interacted with the Avengers before (Falcon fight scene), has good opinions of Captain America, suggested to Hank Pym that the Avengers should be called in during the Ant Man movie events.
- Black Panther: Seeking revenge for his father's death at the hands of Bucky Barnes. Also now ruler of Wakanda, and Wakanda was a major pusher for the Sokovia Accords as a result of collateral damage to Wakandans from Avengers operating without oversight.
- Spider-Man: Stark recruited him. Has personal beliefs that if you see bad things happening, and have the ability to act and don't, it's on you. Perhaps more concisely "With great power comes great responsiblity" - the intent of the Sokovia Accords.
- Falcon: loyal to Rogers
- Black Widow: complicated - again, feels guilt for previous actions and looking to assuage that guilt. Distrusts big organisations, but understands that it might be better working with the system than against it. Eventually acts to try and end the conflict as soon as possible without dragging out a Civil War.
- War Machine: Trained under the US military, comfortable following a chain of command etc., and Stark's best friend. Also thinks it's dangerous to ignore the will of the United Nations, and all the governments within, to follow Captain America's line of personal accountability.
- Vision: Notes that there's a correlation between the Avengers and a response against the Avengers. Seeks to follow the path towards "peace in our time", and contains a version of the protocols to defend Earth programmed by Tony Stark (but is not an AI).
- Scarlet Witch: Hugely distrusts Tony Stark's judgment, and wary of big governments. One of the plot points earlier in the movie was when Tony Stark and Vision attempted to quietly "imprison" her in the Avengers facility in the interests of the greater good, so she has already experienced the downside of controlling enhanced individuals being taken too far, and the loss of liberty.

Scarlet Witch and Hawkeye are the hardest to pin down - but again, their motivations come from their characters backstories.